Does target="_blank" redirect to a new window or a new tab?
Just starting out coding for the first time, learning it on freeCodeCamp.org and doing the web development course learning html currently, and ran into target="_blank". freeCodeCamp.org says that it should redirect a link into a new window or tab. Which one is it? Window or Tab? Does it really redirect the link for it to sometimes go to a new window and sometimes go to a new tab? Help needed and much appreciated, thanks, Ishan.
I didn't really understand how to test it as I don't exactly know where to run my codes.

target="_blank" is an attribute of HTML  element and onclick it opens the link in a "New Tab".

I think its a new window ... that on most desktop browsers opens in a new tab. Not something to worry about overmuch. Just do it and see what happens ... that is your answer.

<a href="example.com" target="_blank">abc</a> 
When you click on "abc" it will redirect you to xyz website on a new tab
